# Creating a text editor using deque in C++ trying to add a command that deletes current line. But either seg faults or doesn't delete what I want

Tags: c++, stl, text-editor, deque

Trying to create a text editor that passes a .txt file that uses dot commands to edit the text. For example .< moves the pointer for the current line to the front of the document and .p moves the pointer one above. I'm havig a problem impleneting the .k command that is supposed to delete the current line that point is at.

Current code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    deque<string> page;

    string line;

    deque<string>::iterator linePointer = page.begin();

    int beginCounter = 0;

    int erasor = 0;

    while (getline(cin, line))
    {
        if (page.empty())
        {
            if (line[0] == '.' && line[1] == '.')
                line.erase(0, 1);
            page.push_back(line);
            ++linePointer;
            continue;
        }
        if (line[0] == '.')
        {
            switch (line[1])
            {
            case '.':
                line.erase(0,1);
                page.insert(linePointer, line);
                ++linePointer;  
                continue;

            case '<':
                linePointer = page.begin();
                ++beginCounter;
                continue;

            case '>':
            linePointer = page.end();
                continue;


            case 'p':
            --linePointer;
                continue;


            case 'n':
            if(linePointer == page.end()) continue;
            ++linePointer;

                continue;

            case 'k':
                //erasor = distance( page.begin(), linePointer );
                page.erase(linePointer);
                continue;
            }
        }
        page.insert(linePointer, line);
        if(beginCounter >=1) continue;
        ++linePointer;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < page.size(); i++){
        string line = page[i];
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}
```

When trying to parse this file :

```
Made glorious summer by this sun of York;
.<
Delete me!
.p
.k
Now is the winter
of our discontent
```

Compiler creates this:

```
Now is the winter
Delete me!
Made glorious summer by this sun of York;
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: `page.push_back(line); ++linePointer;` This exhibits undefined behavior. `deque::push_back` invalidates all iterators into the deque, including `linePointer`. Same with `insert`

Comment: And of course `page.erase(linePointer)` invalidates `linePointer`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So what would you recommend I do??

Comment: Use a list instead of a deque?

Comment: You could use std::vector and an index instead an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

I gave a try to implement your while loop here. The key point is that when you erase an item from vector, string or deque, iterators pointing to that element and beyond (note this!) gets invalidated. However, what you can do is use the return value of the erase member function which is a valid iterator pointing to the element following the erased element.

As pointed in the comments on your post, this could also be implemented using a std::list. However, a std::list can be expensive to move back and forth in a large file since it does not support random access iterators. Furthermore, erasing an element from a std::list has its own iteration invalidation issues (for this refer to Item 9, Effective STL, Scott Meyers.)

```
while (getline(ifs, line))
{
    if (line[0] == '.')
    {
        if(page.empty()) continue;

        switch (line[1])
        {
        case '.':
            line.erase(0,1);
            linePointer = page.insert(linePointer, line);
            ++linePointer;
            continue;

        case '<':
            linePointer = page.begin();
            continue;

        case '>':
        linePointer = page.end();
            continue;

        case 'p':
        --linePointer;
            continue;

        case 'n':
        if(linePointer == page.end()) continue;
        ++linePointer;
            continue;

        case 'k':
            --linePointer;
            linePointer = page.erase(linePointer);
            continue;
        }
    }

    linePointer = page.insert(linePointer, line);
    ++linePointer;
}
```

Note that the functionality may not be what you are seeking because you did not provide more elaborate examples of what output you expect for a given input.

Comment: Thanks for this! I've implemented what you said and functionality is better.